# Windows API header file that defines functions for dynamic calls

Tags: c++, winapi, dynamic, typedef, dllimport

Is there a C header file available that defines function calls that can be used in place of manually writing out typedefs for every call I want to make?

```
typedef int (WINAPI *pMessageBoxW)(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT)
```

The above is the sort of thing I find myself writing out constantly.

I vaguely recall something being included in the Zeus Trojan source code that defines an extremely large number of windows functions however, I am trying to create a legitimate windows program. Something about including trojan code, even if benign, seems a little off-putting even if we put license issues (though it's not likely that anybody's going to sue me) aside.

I was looking through carberp and zeus code on github and came across

```
#define pSetFilePointer             pushargEx< DLL_KERNEL32, 0xEF48E03A, 27 >
```

In a file called GetApi.h in carberp, this is pretty sneaky and not what I'm interested in.  This is called elsewhere in the code, but the arguments are never strictly defined.  I assume that the authors wrote a compiler directive to say something along the lines of "just trust us" as pushargEx as suggested by its name is using overloading to take however many args are specified and push that to a DLL handle with a specific offset.

If this is what I'm going to have to do to simplify my coding, it's not that the worst thing ever, but surely I'm not the first one to look for a header file specifying

```
typedef int (WINAPI *pMessageBoxW)(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT)
typedef int (WINAPI *pMessageBoxA)(HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT)
typedef int (WINAPI *pSetFilePointer)(HANDLE, LONG, PLONG, DWORD)
...
...
```

Is there a "just trust me" compiler or macro directive I can/should be using to do this?  All I really want to do is to dynamically include numerous WINAPI functions calls while learning something new -- while simultaneously maintaining reasonably clean code.

Is there specific wording I should be using when talking about this?  I feel as though surely it's the words I'm using, not what I'm trying to achieve, that's limiting my ability to find more information on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a C header file available that defines function calls that can be used in place of manually writing out typedefs for every call I want to make?

No.

I'm a little curious as to why you would feel it necessary to use run time linking for functions like `MessageBox` and `SetFilePointer`. I wonder if perhaps you have mistakenly decided that it is a good policy to link to them at run time rather than at load time.

Comment: MessageBox was just an example, but run time resolution does allow for a smaller file size.  I'm trying to dive into function hooking (which doesn't necessarily require such a thing), shellcode, but what I'm dealing with right now is position-independant code and executables, which as I understand do not support linking in this manor.  I know this is additionally a means by which to perform some anti-debugging/analysis but the carberp code above would be more practical for such a thing.

Comment: I doubt that run time linking leads to smaller file size. I'd expect the opposite. Anyway, none of that changes the answer to the question you asked.

Comment: Runtime linking can reduce file size, if imports are resolved by ordinal rather than name. Not generally applicable, but there's a possibility to shrink executables in specific scenarios. @Nahum: Executables are position independent already. Otherwise, ASLR wouldn't work. Modules store function entry points as *Relative Virtual Addresses*, that are simply added as offsets to the module handle by the loader, when resolving imports.